# Pyspark: Delete rows on column condition after groupBy

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my input dataframe:

```
id val    
1  Y
1  N
2  a
2  b
3  N
```

Result should be:

```
id val    
1  Y     
2  a    
2  b
3  N
```

I want to group by on col id which has both Y and N in the val and then remove the row where the column val contains "N".
Please help me resolve this issue as i am beginner to pyspark

Comment: What transformations are you running on the dataframe? Can you give us a bit more context?

Comment: I want to group by on col id and then remove the row where the column val contains "N"

Comment: Why not directly remove those rows with a filter? Why do you need the grouping?

Comment: I only want to remove the row when the particular id has both val Y and N..if there is an id 3 which has only val "N" then it should not remove the row with id 3

Comment: i think as specified by @martinarroyo it would be better to go with filter.

Comment: filter will remove all rows where val is N..i dont want that..

Comment: No, on your filter you can specify multiple conditions, such as id=Y and val=N.

Comment: there can be so many id's with 2 or multiple rows in the dataframe containing 1 million records..so how will you apply the filter condition in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can first identify the problematic rows with a filter for `val=="Y"` and then join this dataframe back to the original one. Finally you can filter for `Null` values and for the rows you want to keep, e.g. `val==Y`. Pyspark should be able to handle the self-join even if there are a lot of rows.
The example is shown below:

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, "Y"), (1, "N"), (1,"X"), (1,"Z"),
(2,"a"), (2,"b"), (3,"N")
], ("id", "val"))

df_Y = df_new.filter(col("val")=="Y").withColumnRenamed("val","val_Y").withColumnRenamed("id","id_Y")
df_new = df_new.join(df_Y, df_new["id"]==df_Y["id_Y"],how="left")
df_new.filter((col("val_Y").isNull()) | ((col("val_Y")=="Y") & ~(col("val")=="N"))).select("id","val").show()
```

The result would be your preferred:

```
+---+---+
| id|val|
+---+---+
|  1|  X|
|  1|  Y|
|  1|  Z|
|  3|  N|
|  2|  a|
|  2|  b|
+---+---+
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution but it does not work if there are more than two values for the same id. For ex if id 1 has four values (Y,N,X,Z)                                                                   df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, "Y"), (1, "N"), 
(1,"X"), (1,"Z"), (3,"N")
], ("id", "val"))

Comment: Hi you can just update the filter in this case: have the last part not `val == "Y"` but `val != "N"`
I will update the answer